# Emacs: How to move forward (after going backwards) in the kill ring?

Tags: emacs

I understand that after yanking (`C-y`) I can move backwards through the kill ring (`M-y`). But sometimes I move past the desired yank - is there a way to move forward in the kill ring? Basically, I want the opposite of `M-y`.

If this is a duplicate, just let me know. I cannot seem to find my answer on SO or Google.

Comment: @Drew has written a library called `browse-kill-ring+.el`:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/browse-kill-ring%2b.el

Comment: there's popup-kill-ring in MELPA too.

Comment: @lawlist: [`browse-kill-ring+`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/browse-kill-ring%2b.el) is an extension of `browse-kill-ring`. The former `require`s the latter.

Comment: @Drew -- Ah . . . thank you -- I hadn't stop to consider that there might have been an underlying library that was already build into Emacs -- Emacs certainly is a learning adventure.

Comment: @lawlist: Not quite. Neither `browse-kill-ring+` nor `browse-kill-ring` is built into Emacs. Both are add-on libraries. The former is an extension of the latter. I offered those extensions to the author of `browse-kill-ring` but never heard back from him. So if you want those extensions then you need both libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prefix arguments with `yank-pop`. From the documentation of <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`yank-pop`<kbd>RET</kbd>

> With no argument, the previous kill is inserted.
>   With argument N, insert the Nth previous kill.
>   If N is negative, this is a more recent kill.

So for example to move 'forward' by one entry after yanking you can do <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>M-y</kbd>. You can also simply use `undo` as @seanmcl suggests.

It can easily get difficult to keep track of entries in the kill-ring. So I would recommend an extension like [`browse-kill-ring`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing) which displays the kill ring and allows you to select the text to be yanked.

Answer (score 9):

There is also <kbd>M--</kbd><kbd>M-y</kbd> which is a shorter equivalent to <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>M-y</kbd>.

Comment: Note for newbie Emacs users including myself: if you happen to press `M-y` too many times while cycling backward in the kill ring you can press `M--` `M-y` to cycle forward once without ever lifting off your finger off of `M`.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply `undo' when you move past it.  Repeated undos will continually move forward.  I agree with @Iqbai though that browse-kill-ring is more appropriate for long chains of yanks.

Comment: After you have moved the kill ring pointer, and do `C-y` it will paste that last pointed to item, and you can only move forward with a prefix argument. `undo` only works in one "yank session".